# PHP get specific word from a string if exists

Tags: php, string, substr

So i have a bunch of file names such as

```
  $filename = "somefile-Page-1.pdf" 
  $filename = "somefile-Page-2.pdf"
```

What im trying to do is get the page number in the file name

```
so that $pageNumber will resurn Page-1
```

Iv tried the follwoing:

```
$pageNum = substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, 'Page'));
```

but this ends up returning

```
 somefile-
```

Comment: Why are you starting at 0. you should start the substring where the filename starts. `substr($filename, strpos($filename, 'Page'), -4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filename = 'somefile-Page-2.pdf';
preg_match('/(Page\-(\d+))\.pdf/i', $filename, $matches);
```

and the matches array will have the format:

> array (size=3)
>
> 0 => string 'Page-2.pdf' (length=10)
>
> 1 => string 'Page-2' (length=6)
>
> 2 => string '2' (length=1)

Answer (score 0):

In your example your substring starts at 0 and ends at "Page" position. Try

```
$pageNum = substr($filename, strpos($filename, 'Page'), -4);
```

to get the part from "Page" until the end (without period and extension, thus -4).

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "somefile-Page-2.pdf";

public function getPageNumber($filename) {
    // Explodes on "-" 
    $explodedFilename = explode('-', $filename); 

    // Find the key to the Page word
    $keyToPage = array_search("Page", $explodedFilename); 

    // If the key is found and the next array item exists, which contains the number, go and return it
    if( $keyToPage && isset($explodedFilename[$keyToPage++]) ) { 
        return $explodedFilename[$keyToPage] . "-" . $explodedFilename[$keyToPage++];
    }

    return null;
|
```